# Is there a pattern for a "matrix style" comparison?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Is there a canonical algorithm or pattern for the following style of decision: You have n resources (let's say two for now, resource 1 and resource 2). Consider the pseudo code:

```
Request for X units, requiring resources 1 and 2 {
If (enough of resource 1)
   if (enough of resource 2)
      fulfill request for X units. 
   else (not enough of resource 2)
      partially fulfill, to max of resource 2
else (not enough of resource 1)
   if (there is enough of resource 2)
      partially fulfill, to max of resource 1. 
   else (not enough of resource 2)
      partially fulfill, to max of resource 2
}
```

Things get out of hand very quickly with n > 2, and there is a lot of duplicated code. Is there a more efficient way to implement this algorithm?

I'm programming in Javascript for this problem, if that matters.

Comment: A simple loop should do the trick, shouldn't it?

Comment: I am doing that right now (with the above if statement layout), but with large n, the number of cross checks gets out of hand.

Comment: In your example, it seems that one resource has priority over the other? What if you don't have enough of both resource, but you don't have enough of the first to fulfill up to whatever the second allows?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fk6coz8a/

Comment: @juvian - thanks. If it was an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is an example where you can set any number of resources, associating them with a key and setting the quantity of the units you want and the cost for each resource. Has 2 functions, one which gets the maximum units possible with the resources you have, and one which spends those resources:

```
function Request(qty){
    this.quantity = qty; // quantity of units to make
    this.required = {}; // required resources
    var request = this;

    this.checkAvailability = function(resources){
        var available = request.quantity;
        var spent = {};
        var left = {};
        for(var key in request.required){ // for each required resource
            var max = Math.min(request.quantity, Math.floor(resources[key].quantity/request.required[key])) // set max as wanted quantity or available quantity if it is less than wanted
            available = Math.min(max, available) // update max of units you can make 
        }
        return available
    }

    this.spendResources = function(resources, qty){ // spend required resources
        for(var key in request.required){
            resources[key].quantity -= request.required[key]*qty;
        }
    }

}

function Resource(qty){
    this.quantity = qty;
}

var available = {
    1: new Resource(200),
    2: new Resource(140)
}

var request = new Request(7)
request.required = {1: 40, 2: 30}
var availableQty = request.checkAvailability(available)
request.spendResources(available, availableQty)
console.log(availableQty, available)
```

Working Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fk6coz8a/

Answer (score 1):

I would loop over each resource, calculate each time how much of the product I may build out of it assuming all the other resources are available in sufficient amount, and restrain production to the lowest projected amount of all. This is basically a *fold* over the resources, which is supported by the `reduce` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Thanks - that's a good idea. I like splitting things out into calculating what you need, and then spending it (Also in comments to question, above).